# Implementing inheritance in AngularJS directives

Tags: javascript, oop, angularjs, inheritance, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to implement OOP inheritance in AngularJS directives to make reusable controls.  I'm using [Base2's Class definition](https://code.google.com/p/base2/source/browse/trunk/src/base2/Base.js) for inheritance.  What I was thinking was to implement a directive like this

```
<control-input type="text" name="vendor_name"></control-input>
```

Then I would created a `BaseControl` class for common functionality

```
angular.module('base',[]).factory('BaseControl', function() {
  return Base.extend({
    'restrict': 'E',
    'require': '^parentForm'
    /* ... */
  };
});
```

And then I would create specific controls

```
angular.module('controls',['base']).factory('TextControl', function(BaseControl) {
  return BaseControl.extend({
    /* specific functions like templateUrl, compile, link, etc. */
  };
});
```

The issue is that I want to use a single directive `control-input` and specify the type in the attributes, but the problem is when I create the directive, I don't know how to retrieve the type

```
angular.module('controls',['controls']).directive('control-input', function(TextControl) {
   /* here it should go some code like if (type === 'text') return new TextControl(); */
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `attrs` params of the link function to get the type of each directive. Take a look at the code below and check your console.  (http://jsbin.com/oZAHacA/2/)

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.6/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script>
      var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

     myApp.directive('controlInput', [function () {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          link: function (scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
              console.log(iAttrs.type);
          }
        };
     }]);

    </script>
  </head>
 <body>

    <control-input type="text" name="vendor_name"></control-input>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, the problem is that I want to return the DDO itself as an inheritance, replace the `return {...}` by `return new TextControl(...)` or something like that, by that time I have no information about attributes nor scope.